# docker uild error on Android checking context: no permission to read from /config/sdcardfs/remove_userid

Tags: android, linux, docker, linux-kernel, fuse

i saw some similar issues but could solve my problem:

I tried to install docker on **Android** and could after some modifications on kernel, so now docker client and server both are running, **by sudo docker version**. i need to build a sample image but after running i get this error:

error checking context: no permission to read from /config/sdcardfs/remove_userid

i don't know what to do because even this command shows me no permission to read , even with root access. I also modified the permissions of **"remove_userid" to rwx**, but no change happens. ***Also, sudo cat remove_userid return no permission to read!!!!*** ( I searched and found out that this file is under somehow virtual file system, no idea about it. i ran it with root access and under root path even, but not working.
I am working with android and do not have systemd and system ctl. although i am not sure if these can help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , we have to make a new directory and put Dockerfile and other files in there, then build the docker :

sudo docker build -t img1 /newdockerfolder